# Vue js: compare elements in the array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in my code below i'm trying to check if the entered email is NOT exists in the API data `this.users.email`
but it giving me error: can't read email of undefined.However, when i console.log(this.users) i can see all my data , but when i console.log(this.users.email) it giving me undefined, any idea on how to solve it?

[image]

```js
export default {
  data() {
   
    return {
 
      error: "",
      message:"",
      users:[],
    
          Reset: false,
      login: {
        email: "",

        password: "",
     
      },
      SendEmail:{
      email:"",
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
   
    Submit(){
   
      try {
  
       questionService.RequestResetPassword(this.SendEmail).then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
       
       
      
        });
    }
     catch (e) { if(!this.sendEmail.email.includes(this.users.email)){ //error here
      this.error="enter an existing email";
    }}
  
    }
    
  },

    mounted: function () {
    

   questionService.getAllUsers().then((jsonData) => {
      this.users = jsonData.data.response;
      
    
        
       console.log(this.users) // can appear properly
        console.log(this.users.email) //undefined
        

      })}
};
```

Comment: You tried to get an email from the array, but not from the user. Try to get this.users[0].email